# Sudoku Grid Tester - list index out of range

Tags: python, computer-science

As part of a computer science assignment I was required to test whether a Sudoku grid is valid 
or invalid. I have debugged the program a few times, and inserted the values of the second iteration into the problem area, and the correct value is returned - so there is clearly something I am overlooking.

The following section of code is giving me problems:

```
array = ['752639841','348751926','169284573','923146785','481975362','675823194','816392457','294517638','537468219']
columncheck=True
a=0
b=0
x=1
for i in range(9):
    x=1
    for c in range(9):
        x=x*int((array[a])[b])
        a=a+1
    if x!=362880:
        columncheck=False   
        print(x)
    b=b+1
```

It returns the following error: "builtins.IndexError: list index out of range" for line 9 in the second iteration where c=1, a=1, x=7 and b=0.

Hopefully there is an easy fix for this, thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

value of `a` becomes 9 in your code, which ofcourse is not a valid index for `array`

```
for i in range(9):
    x=1
    for c in range(9):
        print(a)  # notice this output
        print(b)
        x=x*int((array[a])[b])
        a=a+1
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruv. Adding a=0 below x=1 fixes the problem.